# kinect no working

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I follow this tutorial http://learn.turtlebot.com/ but I have a problem with the step 8. I am working with virtualbox, ubuntu 14.04 and kobuki. I didn't make the step 7 because I didn't have a netbook. But I can move the robot...

The picture describe my error:
http://hpics.li/3464516

Thank you for your responses

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205991/kinect-no-working/) by [nerozalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/21989/nerozalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm guessing that the environment for the left terminal is not set correctly? Have you sourced your workspaces `setup.bash` file? Do you have `openni_launch` installed?

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0